# Select only one check box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, checkbox, ionic2

I am using ionic 2 and angular 2 for a small project. and I want the user to be able to only select one checkbox from the ones provided. I added and action listener whenever a checkbox is checked but not sure on what the function should really execute.

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index">
      <ion-label [innerHTML]="category.name"></ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox color="royal" checked="category.value" (click)="Selection(i,categories);"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
```

Here is the sample of the JSON object

```
    categories = [
    {
      name: 'Car Keys',
      value: 'false'
  },
  {
      name: 'Phone',
      value: 'false'
  },
  {
      name: 'ID/Drivers License',
      value: 'false'
  },
  {   name: 'Wallet',
      value: 'false'
  },
  {   name: 'Other',
      value: 'false'
  }]
```

I am passing the index of the categories into the function but not sure what else to check for. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use radio buttons instead?

Comment: update the post with sample json and can you create a plunker?

Comment: why are you writing `<ion-label [innerHTML]="category.name"></ion-label>` instead of `<ion-label>{{category.name}}></ion-label>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could easiest be achieved using radio buttons, but if you want to use checkboxes, this would mean you should disable the other checkboxes when one is chosen.

The array you have, change the `value` property to a boolean value `false` instead, which we can work with. Then when a checkbox is chosen, it would invoke your `Selection`-function, which sets the other checkboxes' value to to `true` when one is chosen, keeping the one chosen as false. When user unchecks checkbox, all checkboxes values are again `false`. To this we use the unique name property, which is passed to the function and when we iterate the categories to see which one is checked. So your function:

```
Selection(name: string) {
   this.categories.forEach(x => {
       if(x.name !== name) {
           x.value = !x.value
       }
   })
}
```

And to your template, add the disabled option:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index">
  <ion-label>{{category.name}}</ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox [disabled]="categories[i].value" (click)="Selection(category.name);"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

### **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YbM26sSDYEv9fnZA8lth?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you, just exactly what I wanted to do. Will also give radio buttons a try.

Comment: You are welcome, glad I could help! Since it solved your issue, please consider accepting the answer :)