# select only one checkbox in a group in angular 4

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular5, angular4-forms

I am using angular 4. I have two checkboxes in a Group and I want to make sure only one of them can be checked and I can be deselect both. So if one is checked the other has to be unchecked. I have written below code. I want to select only once at time from these checkboxes.

```
<div class="btn-group-toggle w-100 Filtertogglebtns d-block d-md-none" data-toggle="buttons">
                              <label class="btn btn-light mr-2">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="filteroptions" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></i>
                              </label>
                              <label class="mt-md-0 btn btn-light">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="filteroptions" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i>
                              </label>
                            </div>
```

I want like this [reference link](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/apSE3cIXA7DIvulBfNGX?p=preview&preview) but using angular 4. Please help me with this.

Comment: It looks like you need a radio button instead of a checkbox. They are intended for that.

Comment: No I also want to deselect both. Please check reference link for what I want.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879446/select-only-one-check-box) can help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select only one check box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879446/select-only-one-check-box)

Comment: given link they are using ionic checkbox